# Can I add roles in a private git repo as a meta/dependancy in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of Ansible roles that I'd like to reuse. They are each kept in a repo in a private BitBucket.

I want to add projects that are hosted in Git as meta/dependencies for my the roles I'm working on but I can't quite figure out the syntax is.

In this non-working example, a role requires another role to be deployed first with parameters prior to running.

FYI, The remote role "acm_layout" is intended to create a standard directory layout for the server, so that my role can run knowing that all of the standard directories already exist.

```
---
dependencies:
   - { role: project_keys } # Works fine, just reuses a local role

   - name: acm_layout # Doesn't work, but this is what I want to fix
     src: ssh://git@bigcompany.com/acm/acm_layout.git
     scm: git
     version: feature/initialize
     application_storage_dir: "{{base_storage_dir}}"
     application_data_dir: "{{app_data_dir}}"
```

When I runt this I get the following error:

```
ERROR! the role 'acm_layout' was not found in [lots of paths deleted]

The error appears to have been in '/home/zs5fgzg/_tmp/horizon_deployment_scf/ansible/roles/horizon_layout/meta/main.yaml': line 4, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

   - { role: horizon_keys }
   - src: ssh://git@bigcompany.com:7999/acm/acm_layout.git
     ^ here
```

So what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ansible-galaxy` install with `requirements.yml` option to get roles remotely. Create `requirements.yml` as follows:

- https://github.com/avinash6784/elk-stack/blob/master/requirements.yml

And run the following command:

```
$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml -p roles/
```

For more info on how to get roles using ansible-galaxy please visit
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy.html

Comment: Great answer, works for me! As I also develop the role that I wanted to reuse in another Ansible play/role, I stumbled upon the following error: `[WARNING]: - yourRoleNameHere was NOT installed successfully: this role does not appear to have a meta/main.yml file.` Just make sure, that the dependend role has a valid `meta/main.yml` file - you can create a role stub containing such a file with the `ansible-galaxy init yourRoleNameHere` command - or derive it from this example here: https://github.com/jonashackt/molecule-ansible-docker-vagrant/blob/master/docker/meta/main.yml